# NullReferenceException & using methods without direct reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Gamemanager : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject AttackButton; //reference to attack button game object
public GameObject RocketGO; // reference to rocket game object
public GameObject EnemySpawner;//reference to meteorite spawner gameobject
public GameObject navbuttons;
public GameObject Power1SpawnerGO; // reference to power1 spawner
public GameObject Enemy1bluespawner;
// Use this for initialization

public enum GamemanagerState
{
    Opening ,
    Gameplay ,
    Gameover,

}

GamemanagerState GMState;

void Start ()
{

    GMState = GamemanagerState.Opening;


}

void UpdateGameManagerState()
{
    switch(GMState)
    {
    case GamemanagerState.Opening:
        //set attack button to true
        AttackButton.SetActive(true);

        //hide game over

        //set navigational buttons to false
        navbuttons.SetActive(false);


            break;

    case GamemanagerState.Gameplay:
        //set attack button false
        AttackButton.SetActive(false);

        //set navbuttons to true
        navbuttons.SetActive(true);

        //set playership to active
        RocketGO.GetComponent<Rocketdamage>().Init();

        //Start EnemySpawner
        EnemySpawner.GetComponent<meteoritespawner>().startEnemySpawner();
        Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemy1Spawner>().startEnemy1blueSpawner(); // Enemy blue spawner


        //Active Rocket bullete fire
        RocketGO.GetComponent<Rocketshooting>().startBulleteFire();

        //Activate Enemyblue1 bulletefire
        Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemyblue1shooting>().startEBulleteFire();

        //Active power1 spawner
        Power1SpawnerGO.GetComponent<PowerSpawner>().startPower1Spawner();



            break;

    case GamemanagerState.Gameover:

        //stop enemy spawner
        EnemySpawner.GetComponent<meteoritespawner>().StopEnemySpawning();
        Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemy1Spawner>().StopEnemy1blueSpawning();

        //DeActive Rocket bullete fire 
        RocketGO.GetComponent<Rocketshooting>().StopBulleteFire();

        //Stop power1 spawning
        Power1SpawnerGO.GetComponent<PowerSpawner>().StopPower1Spawning();

        //Deactive Enemyblue1 Bullete fire
        Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemyblue1shooting>().StopEBulleteFire();


        //display gameover

        //set game state to opening state after 8 sec
        Invoke("changeToOpeningState" , 8f);
        break;

    }

}

public void setGameManagerState(GamemanagerState state)
{
    GMState = state;
    UpdateGameManagerState ();
}

//call this function when player call attack button
public void Startpaly()
{
    GMState = GamemanagerState.Gameplay;
    UpdateGameManagerState ();


}

public void changeToOpeningState()
{
    setGameManagerState (GamemanagerState.Opening);
}
}
```

This is my script.......and everything is running fine! But the line number 67 and 89 i.e.

//line no 67

```
  Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemyblue1shooting>().startEBulleteFire();
```

and:

//line no 89

```
 Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemyblue1shooting>().StopEBulleteFire();
```

under UpdateGameManagerState() function.

are giving me `NullreferenceException`.

After so much of thinking, I have come up with this issue that may have been occurring!

- Here `Enemy1bluespawner` is object(with which Spawning script is attached) to spawn enemy....and `Enemyprefab` is attached to `Enemy1bluespawner`...but however, I am able to call all the scripts/methods of Enemy PREFAB(Without direct reference of Enemy prefab - I don't know why?).
- Everything working fine but line number 67 and 89 is giving me `NullreferenceException`.

**Scenario** - I have empty object - `Enemy1bluespawner` with which `Enemyspawning` script is attached - which spawn the enemy at particular interval of time.........

So, when I am calling this function :

```
Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemyblue1shooting>().startEBulleteFire();
```

To start bullete fire of the enemy but now enemy is not on the screen it will come after 5 seconds

The enemy is not on the screen it comes after 5 seconds - so may be that's why Unity is throwing `NullreferenceException`(at runtime)

Questions:

- How am I able to access Enemy prefab scripts/methods without direct reference thru `Enemy1bluespawn` Object?
- Solution to remove `NullreferenceException`. When enemy is not on screen and I am calling methoda related to it.

I hope you guys are understanding it. Any little help will be great. Thank you! :) :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference the `Enemy1Spawner` script, but never the `Enemyblue1shooting`. For what I'm understanding, your goal is to **spawn** enemies with the  `Enemy1Spawner` script, and those spawned enemies are the objects that have the `Enemyblue1shooting` component (that will actually shoot).

If I'm right, you'll have to get the `GameObject` of the spawned enemy and then use the `GetComponent` method. What seems to be happening is a `NullPointerException` because the spawner doesn't have a `Enemyblue1shooting` component; the object that has it is it's child.

Try making a method in the `Enemy1bluespawner` script that returns the enemy at hand and, only then, using `GetComponent<Enemyblue1shooting>()` to get the right component. That'll do the trick.

**Example:**

```
public GameObject GetEnemy(int n)
{
    return enemies.get(n); // Gets the n enemy in your array
}

...

Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemy1Spawner>().startEnemy1blueSpawner(); // Enemy blue spawner

GameObject enemy = Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemy1Spawner>().GetEnemy(0);
enemy.GetComponent<Enemyblue1shooting>().startEBulleteFire();
```

Don't forget to do some null validation. The perfect scenario would be returning the script itself, not a GameObject, but this way it may be a bit easier to see.

That might be also your question about calling prefab's methods. You don't call a prefab's method; you call the method of the instantiated prefab (the spawned enemy).

Answer (score 0):

easiest but not the best is

```
if(Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemyblue1shooting>()!=null)
Enemy1bluespawner.GetComponent<Enemyblue1shooting>().startEBulleteFire();
```